# NumPy: 1D numpy array to slice a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

How can I extract the elements of a list corresponding to the indices contained in a 1D `numpy.ndarray`?

Here is an example:

```
list_data = list(range(1, 100))
arr_index = np.asarray([18, 55, 22])
arr_index.shape

list_data[arr_index]  # FAILS
```

I want to be able to retrieve the elements of `list_data` corresponding to   `arr_index`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.take`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) -

```
import numpy as np
np.take(list_data,arr_index)
```

Sample run -

```
In [12]: list_data = list(range(1, 20))

In [13]: list_data
Out[13]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]

In [14]: arr_index = np.asarray([3, 5, 12])

In [15]: np.take(list_data,arr_index)
Out[15]: array([ 4,  6, 13])
```

Comment: So the first argument is `array_like`, which means that the list is cast to `ndarray` before use?

Comment: @Kasra What do you mean by *simple* indexing?

Comment: @Kasra Apparently simple indexing expects the first input to be a numpy array.

Comment: `>>> list_data = np.arange(1, 100)
>>> list_data[arr_index]
array([19, 56, 23])
`

Comment: @fgnu: It's cast to ndarray. You can see in the [source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.9.1/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L53) that for a list input, `take` ends up calling `_wrapit`, which calls `asarray`. Personally, I'd either use a list comprehension or convert the list to an array at the earliest possible point.

Comment: @Divakar Ahan in that perspective yeah! indeed

Comment: @user2357112 Just the information I was looking for. Eventually looking to make this more efficient, but the list is the return of a method, and is used only once, so not sure that there will be significant benefit to casting to `ndarray` over letting `take` `asarray` it.

Comment: @fgnu: Well, if you're only using it once, a list comprehension won't have to go over every element of the list. Which option is fastest depends on how many items you expect to take. You might also try something like `map(list_data.__getitem__, arr_index)` and see if that helps.

Comment: @user2357112 I expect to take about 3% of the elements of a long list (20K elements). Which idiom would you suggest as being more performant?

Comment: In my timing tests, list comprehension is the winner.  The array creation overhead is too large.

Comment: @fgnu: You'd have to time it to be sure. Going by hpaulj's timings, the list comprehension looks like your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

OR

```py
import numpy as np
list_data = list(range(1, 100))
arr_index = np.asarray([18, 55, 22])
arr_index.shape

new_ = [list_data[i] for i in arr_index]

>> [19, 56, 23]
```

**Note**

`list_data = list(range(1, 100)` can be replaced by `list_data = range(1, 100)`

`arr_index = np.asarray([18, 55, 22])` can be replaced by `arr_index = np.array([18, 55, 22])`

Comment: In py3, you need `list(range())` unless you are iterating right away.

Answer (score 1):

I just did some timing tests:

```
In [226]: ll=list(range(20000))    
In [227]: ind=np.random.randint(0,20000,200)

In [228]: timeit np.array(ll)[ind]
100 loops, best of 3: 3.29 ms per loop

In [229]: timeit np.take(ll,ind)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.34 ms per loop

In [230]: timeit [ll[x] for x in ind]
10000 loops, best of 3: 65.1 µs per loop

In [231]: arr=np.array(ll)
In [232]: timeit arr[ind]
100000 loops, best of 3: 6 µs per loop
```

The list comprehension clearly is the winner.  Indexing an array is clearly faster, but the overhead of creating that array is substantial.

Converting to an object dtype array is faster.  I'm a little surprised, but it must be because it can convert without parsing:

```
In [236]: timeit np.array(ll,dtype=object)[ind].tolist()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.04 ms per loop
```